# Unsaved buffer warning when switching files/buffers

Tags: vim, text-editor

I am using FuzzyFinder with Vim to open files and switch between buffers. It works like a charm except when the current file I am working on has some changes. Vim wouldn't let me switch the buffer till I save it:

```
"E37: No write since last change (add ! to override)".
```

Is there a way of suppressing this warning unless I am quitting the editor? All I want to do it switch to a different buffer for referencing some code and switch back.

Comment: Ha ha. I just had to search for this again today and it came up right on top. I guess my google-fu edit worked!

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I think you can use `:set hidden`.

Answer (score 21):

Use the `:set hidden` option and Vim will hide the buffer until you come back to it.

You can also use `:set confirm` to deal with the unsaved buffer warning more conveniently.

Comment: Thanks. :set hidden works as I expected. :set confirm makes things a little more obtrusive by asking me to save the buffer each time I want to switch to a new buffer.

Comment: @deepakg Nope. When you set confirm, then it will prompt only when you quit

Comment: @Sundar Nope. http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'confirm' "When 'confirm' is on, certain operations that would normally fail because of unsaved changes to a buffer... instead raise a dialog asking if you wish to save the current file(s)"

`set hidden` is really what you want here I think. http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'hidden'

Comment: @alecbz Believe the more convenient is to have *both* set. Set `hidden`: you can switch buffers w/o confirmation. **And** set `confirm`: you get a *"Save yes / no / cancel"* option on `:quit` + if one do for example `:e`. With *only* `hidden` set you get a *"Save or use ! to override"* instead of *"Save yes / no / cancel"*

Comment: That said: personally I prefer to not have it set. With `confirm` I'm too paranoid by that I'd accidentally press wrong option. It is so rare I need it anyway.